# Subset of time data

Tags: r, time, subset

I'm trying to make a simple subset of a df based on a POSIXct variable, but it doesn't work...

```
a2001 <- subset(anillas, anillas$data=="21-03-2001")
```

it gives "0 obs. of 74 variables"

are those variables different in any way I don't know?

Tks.

Ok, so this is part of the `str(anillas)`

```
 $ rc          : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ss          : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ tg          : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ug          : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ data        : POSIXct, format: "2001-03-21" "2001-03-23" ...
```

Comment: please add the output of `dput(head(anillas))` to your question.  Also, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: dput showed a very very long list so it will take me a little while to prepare a short one (based on what you suggest)(i'm just begining with R)

Comment: is the problem that your date format in `subset(annillas, anillas$data == "21-03-2001")` is different to the date format in `anillas$data`? try `which (anillas$data=="21-03-2001")` to see if anything is returned. If not, try again with `which(anillas$data=="2001-03-21")`.  I suspect that `a2001 <- subset(anillas, anillas$data=="2001-03-21")` might do what you want.

Comment: in both cases I get `integer(0)`, with the original UK date format and with the US format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compare with what's comparable. In your attempt you compared a `POSIXct` object with a `character` string.
You need first to convert the date you want to subset `anillas` with to `POSIXct`:

```
date1 <- strptime("21-03-2001","%d-%m-%Y")
a2001 <- subset(anillas, data==date1)
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with their data and what they show isn't impossible.  If the time is exactly midnight, no time is printed by default. For example: `str(as.POSIXct("2012-11-21",tz="GMT"))`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich fair enough, I didn't know that (never encountered the case before to be honest, and thought it would print `00:00:00`). I tried to reproduce it but in my haste didn't specify `tz="GMT"`, hence the `01:00:00`.

Comment: I created date1 and then subset... but a2001 still `0 obs of 74 variables`

Comment: Ok, finally I give up, I created a new variable with `year()` of package `lubridate`and everything worked fine. Thanks you all!!